# Problemas ao passar props para state do componente React

Tags: javascript, react

Problemas ao passar props para state do componente, quando no componente faço `console.log(this)` a props cliente esta lá com todos os campos, mais quando faço `console.log(this.props)` ele me mostra o state vazio. o `this.state.cliente2` esta sempre vazio. Onde estou errando. já passei horas tentando descobrir.

> app.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.svg'
import './App.css'
import Lista from './Lista'

class App extends Component {

  constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {cliente: {}}
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    let ClienteJson = {
      'id': 1,
      'cadastro': '2017-04-06T01:07:48.000Z',
      'nome': 'Alexandre',
      'email': 'alex@example.com',
      'cidade': 'PIRAPORA',
      'estado': 'MG'
    }

    this.setState({cliente: ClienteJson})
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div className='App'>
        <div className='App-header'>
          <img src={logo} className='App-logo' alt='logo' />
          <h2>Welcome to React {this.state.cliente.nome}</h2>
        </div>

        <Lista cliente={this.state.cliente} />

        <p className='App-intro' />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App
```

> componente: Lista

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Lista extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {cliente2: this.props.cliente };
    console.log(this);
  }

  componentDidMount (prors) {

  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul> <li> {this.state.cliente2.nome} </li> </ul>
        <ul> <li> {this.props.cliente.nome} </li> </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está ocorrendo porque você está atualizando o valor depois que o componente é renderizado.

> **componentWillMount:** é chamado uma vez só, tanto do lado cliente quando do servidor antes da renderização acontecer.
>
> **componentDidMount:** chamado uma vez só, só na parte do cliente, depois da renderização.
>
> **shouldComponentUpdate:** chamado depois da renderização quando as propriedades e o estado está sendo definido. Ele retorna true ou false para dizer se o elemento deve atualizar.
>
> **componentWillUnmount:** chamado quando desejamos desmontar o componente.

Então em seu arquivo `app.js` altere `componentDidMount` para `componentWillMount` deixando assim:

```
componentWillMount() {
    let ClienteJson = {
        'id': 1,
        'cadastro': '2017-04-06T01:07:48.000Z',
        'nome': 'Alexandre',
        'email': 'alex@example.com',
        'cidade': 'PIRAPORA',
        'estado': 'MG'
    }
    this.setState({cliente: ClienteJson})
}
```

Pode ver funcionando no [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/kwzy4nr9jr).

#### Atualização

Como bem lembrado pelo amigo Sergio, o método `constructor` só é chamado uma vez, assim todo `state` definido dentro deste método, é executado antes do método `componentDidMount`.

Comment: `+1` - podias juntar também o `constructor` na explicação e referir que ele também só é corrido uma vez, daí que `this.state = {cliente2: this.props.cliente };` é corrido antes de App correr o `componentDidMount`